# How to determine question in decision tree?

Tags: statistics, data-science, computer-science

Lets say we have a decision tree having question at node is petal length >= 2.5 ,so how does it decide value 2.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

Decision trees use a recursive binary partitioning procedure in order to split the data in groups that are as homogeneous as possible, in terms of the outcome variable.

So the procedure loops through all the explanatory variables and tries a split at each level. It then chooses the split that partitions the data into the fewest misclassifications for the outcome variable.

For a more thorough explanation see this [overview](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/widm.8) or if you have access to it the following book:

Breiman, L.; Friedman, J. H.; Olshen, R. A. and Stone, C. J. Classification and regression trees. Monterey, CA: Wadsworth and Brooks-Cole, 1984

Comment: I want to know how it exactly works ? I think it select best feature according to Gini impurity index(i used) then it select the question from best feature again according to Gini. Please correct me if i wrong.